# Linq operation with datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I am populating a DataTable using ADO.NET and binding a DataList and it works. But when I try to extract only 10 records using Linq from DataTable as shown below, my code gives an error:

```
var xx=dt.asEnumerable().take(10).tolist();
dglist.datasource=xx;
dglist.databind();

<asp:DataList ID="dglist" runat="server" 
    RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    RepeatLayout="Table" CellPadding="1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
           <asp:Image runat="server" id="Image1" 
                 src='<%# Eval("photos") %>'  BorderWidth="0"
                 alt="" style="width:300px;height:300px;display:block;"/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

My DataTable has one column called "photos". I am getting an error when I bind to a DataList. Please guide me on how I can use Linq to extract 10 records from DataTable and bind DataList with 10 records.

I have another question.

What does `datatable.asEnumerable()` mean and what it does do? It seems to convert a DataTable by asEnumerable() but to what?

Comment: Regarding your last question it converts database to a collection (i.e. IEnumerable<T>)

Comment: What is the Exception or the message that you got?

Comment: no column found called "photo"

Comment: is that code is ok? i populate my datatable using ado.net not linq to sql.

Comment: Could you try removing the .tolist() part (var xx=dt.asEnumerable().take(10);). I've had some weird result with converting my IEnumerable to List in the past, but could not explain why. You could also put a breakpoint when executing the code to see what are the attributes of your xx var and see if it really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTable` implements the `IListSource` interface that is way it's supports databinding to column names (so `Eval("photos")` works). But when you call `AsEnumerable()` on the `DataTable` it will return an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` where the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) objects won't have the property named `photos` that is why you get the exception. But you can make it work if you use an indexer in your eval with the column name:

```
var xx = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(10).ToList();
dglist.DataSource = xx;
dglist.DataBind();

<asp:DataList ID="dglist" runat="server" 
    ...
           <asp:Image runat="server" id="Image1" 
                 src='<%# Eval("[photos]") %>'  BorderWidth="0"
                 alt="" style="width:300px;height:300px;display:block;"/>
    ...
</asp:DataList>
```

Or you use the [AsDataView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907985.aspx) extension method. The `OfType<object>()` is required to make the non generic collection to a generic one to support LINQ. In this case you don't need to use an indexer in your `Eval` method:

```
var xx = dt.AsDataView().OfType<object>().Take(10).ToList();
dglist.DataSource = xx;
dglist.DataBind();

<asp:DataList ID="dglist" runat="server" 
    ....
           <asp:Image runat="server" id="Image1" 
                 src='<%# Eval("photos") %>'  BorderWidth="0"
                 alt="" style="width:300px;height:300px;display:block;"/>
    ....
</asp:DataList>
```